# index value doesn't match in r

Tags: r, indexing

I summary the table before I do any changes. Then I extract the data which exclude the data with empty value and "I or II NOS" and assigned to a1 and a2 separately.
a1 has the right data. But it shows that a2 still has 4 "I or II NOS" data. When I tried to index the "I or II NOS" data of the original table, it gives 10 rows but the values of 4 rows are not "I or II NOS". How does this happen? Could someone help me? I don't have enough reputations to paste the result screenprint picture so I only paste the code. Thanks in advance.

```
a1 = a[AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE!='',]

a2 = a1[AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE!='I or II NOS',]
```

Sorry, I updated the question and pasted the whole codes.

```
library("cgdsr", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("R.oo", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("R.methodsS3", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
# Create CGDS object
mycgds = CGDS("http://www.cbioportal.org/public-portal/")
test(mycgds)
# Get list of cancer studies at server
getCancerStudies(mycgds)[, c(1,2)]

mycancerstudy = getCancerStudies(mycgds)[78,1]
# Get available case lists (collection of samples) for a given cancer study
getCaseLists(mycgds,mycancerstudy)[,1]

mycaselist = getCaseLists(mycgds,mycancerstudy)[2,1]

# Get available genetic profiles
getGeneticProfiles(mycgds,mycancerstudy)[,1]

mygeneticprofile = getGeneticProfiles(mycgds,mycancerstudy)[2,1]

# Get clinical data for the case list
myclinicaldata = getClinicalData(mycgds,mycaselist)

# skcm_tcga_rna_seq_v2_mrna_median_Zscores
z_score_caselist = getCaseLists(mycgds,mycancerstudy)[7,1]

# Get data slices for a specified list of genes, genetic profile and case list
WNT5A = getProfileData(mycgds,c('WNT5A'),mygeneticprofile,mycaselist)

# documentation
help('cgdsr')
help('CGDS')

WNT5A_stage = merge(WNT5A,myclinicaldata, by = 'row.names')
WNT5A_stage_table = WNT5A_stage[, c(2, 6)]
a = na.omit(WNT5A_stage_table)
a1 =  a[a$AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE!='']
a2 = a1[AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE!='I or II NOS',]
```

Just update part of the result as follow. You can see the value is not the same as the index.

```
>a1[AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE=='I or II NOS',]
        WNT5A         AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE
  8     712.1645                 I or II NOS
 28      7.5434                 I or II NOS
 33      3.6290                 I or II NOS
 34      8.7881                 I or II NOS
 38    150.3167                 I or II NOS
 47     34.3643                 I or II NOS
 180    19.1529                    Stage IB
 304    20.1072                   Stage IIC
 324    44.0167                    Stage IB
 337 19142.6676                  Stage IIIC
```

Comment: You need to give some sample data and a reproducible example of possible.

Comment: However, it looks like if this is a standard data frame you're not actually sub setting appropriately. You either need `a2 <- a1[a1$AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE != "I or II NOS", ]` or to use `subset`

Comment: Sample data, code, and expected/actual output are required to fully help you with your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm the beginner of using this website. How do I give the sample data? Thanks.

Comment: Cut your code down and include maybe 6 lines of example data and then just the code for the part you don't understand and the results you are getting.  Then also show what the results you want are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, you're not sub setting using the column in the new data frame. You need:

```
a2 = a1[a1$AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE!='I or II NOS',]
```

or

```
a2 = subset(a1, AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE != 'I or II NOS')
```